# SQLAlchemy warning: column won't be part of the declarative mapping

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

trying to build to-do list app with python , flask and sqlalchemy;
when creating a table to database i got this error

i run this command

```
'from app import db'
```

I receive this warning :

```
C:\Users\Mahmoud\.virtualenvs\to-do_list_flask-Gr0Wv-V5\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py:361: SAWarning: Attribute 'item' on class <class 'app.todo'> appears to be a non-schema 'sqlalchemy.sql.column()' object; this won't be part of the declarative mapping
  % (key, cls)
C:\Users\Mahmoud\.virtualenvs\to-do_list_flask-Gr0Wv-V5\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py:361: SAWarning: Attribute 'date' on class <class 'app.todo'> appears to be a non-schema 'sqlalchemy.sql.column()' object; this won't be part of the declarative mapping
  % (key, cls)
```

if i do excute `db.create_all()` the table only has an id column

my script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://postgres:123456@localhost/todo_list'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todo'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item = db.column(db.String(500))
    date = db.column(db.Date)

    def __init__(self, item, date):
        self.item = item
        self.date = date

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods = ['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = request.form['item']
        date = request.form['date']


        data = todo(item, date)
        db.session.add(data)
        db.session.commit()


    return render_template('index.html', item = item, date = date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, debug=True)
```

Comment: `db.Column` with a capital `C`.

Comment: beginner issues :D appreciate it

Comment: @KlausD. I cannot find a duplicate to mark this against so it would be worth turning your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was having this same error. Turns out its just a litte syntax error. Column should be upcase so:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
item = db.Column(db.String(500))
date = db.Column(db.Date)
```

Should fix it.