# flask_sqlalchemy with Oracle

Tags: python, html, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am working on to build a web application and using Oracle database with flask sqlalchemy. The connection is successful with my below code, but when i am running the code i am getting a warning as

SAWarning: Attribute 'CATEGORY' on class  appears to be a non-schema 'sqlalchemy.sql.column()' object; this won't be part of the declarative mapping

My code is working and i am able to run the html, but i feel its the schema name which is missing in my connection. Below is my code. **( i have not mentioned the credentials and host name)** does any one know where the schema needs to be declared or if any one can help resolve the warning.

below is the code i have created.

```
 '''from flask import Flask, render_template, request
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
 from datetime import date, datetime
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'oracle://username:password@host:port/sid'
db = SQLAlchemy(app) 


class Master_dates(db.Model):
    DATA_DATE = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    LOCATN = db.Column(db.String(80))
    CATEGORY = db.column(db.String(120))


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html') '''
```

Comment: **C** olumn with a capital C instead of **c** olumn. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069745/sqlalchemy-warning-column-wont-be-part-of-the-declarative-mapping

Comment: @llja Everlia.. Thank you.. this resolved the warning issue. Can you also help on the schema part. I am using Oracle database and bit confused where i should provide the schema to direct the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Using sqlalchemy i got the same error with the following code

```
class users(db.Model):
    _id=db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(100))
    address=db.Column(db.String(100))
    neighborhood=db.Column(db.String(100))
    city=db.Column(db.String(100))
    phone=db.Column(db.String(100))
    document=db.Column(db.String(100))
    passwoord=db.Column(db.String(100))
    verifyPass=db.Column(db.String(100))
    rol=db.Column(db.String(100))`
```

it got fixed when inside of the same class (in your case will be Master_dates(db.Model)) when i added a constructor to it. like this:

```
def __init__(self, name, address, neighborhood, city, phone, document, passwoord, rol):
    self.name=name
    self.address=address
    self.neighborhood=neighborhood
    self.city=city
    self.phone=phone
    self.document=document
    self.passwoord=passwoord
    self.rol=rol
```

you can try to add this piece of code on your Master_dates(db.Model) class

```
def __init__(self, DATA_DATE, LOCATN, CATEGORY):
    self.DATA_DATE=DATA_DATE
    self.LOCATN=LOCATN
    self.CATEGORY=CATEGORY
```

I hope not to reach out here too late